# A generalization of coupon collector's problem: take an adjacent pair each time.

Tags: probability, expected-value, coupon-collector

We have $n$ distinct kinds of coupons (of unlimited supply), the categories are denoted $1\dots n$.Each time we could draw two coupons, but the two must be of adjacent kind (it could be any of $\{(1,2),(2,3)...,(n-1,n),(n,1)\}$, the probability of drawing any pair is equal). What is the expected number of draws before collecting all $n$ distinct coupons?

Some progress: This is different than just drawing two coupons with replacement randomly, where I already know a formula. And the "pattern" of selecting does not matter, this means drawing $\{(1,3),(2,4)...,(n-1,1),(n,2)\}$ yields the same result.

Comment: Where does the problem come from?

Comment: @quasi I came up with it by myself, simplified from a more difficult real life problem. It is not a homework problem or exam question.

Comment: My sense is that a closed form, summation, or recurrence for the expectation is unlikely to achieved. Of course, a simulation is easy.

Comment: @quasi I've tried basic techniques but had no luck. A solution that is not in a closed form or some references/paper to related problems is fine for me, since I am also not sure how difficult it really is...

Comment: The pattern of the values for the coupon entries _does_ matter. If $n$ is even, with $n\ge 4$, the expected number of draws for the setup where the coupon entries are $2$ apart will, in general, not be equal to the expected number of draws for the setup where the coupon entries are $1$ apart. On the other hand, as long as the graph is a cycle, the results will be the same.

Comment: I think a closed form will be hard.  The usual problem has symmetry because a coupon is either seen or not.  You can compute the expected number of draws to get the next coupon.  Here a draw can yield $0,1,$ or $2$ new coupons and it matters whether a coupon has neighbors.  Say your first two draws are $(1,2)$ and $(4,5)$.  Coupon $3$ is different from all the rest because you can't get a second new one with it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a formula. My fault, I should have realized this problem being equivalent to Project Euler 645, which I have solved earlier. 
$$E(n)=1-n\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{i}\left((-1)^i\binom{n-1}{i}+\frac{\binom{n-i}{i}}{\binom{n-1}{i}}\right)$$
I am now working on the case when a draw includes more than 2 coupons.

Comment: If you have time, can you explain the thinking behind this formula?

Comment: @antkam you can use this formula to enter the thread of Project Euler 645 and see how it is derived

Answer (score 1):

(After the answer of @mayoi, this approach is surpassed, however I am putting it just to show a Markovian approach).

Suppose that, upon turn $t$, you have acquired $m$ coupon out the $n$ avalaible.
Suppose also, for the moment, that the acquired coupon are in succession $\{1,2, \cdots,m \}$.

Now,
 - if you get coupons $(m,m+1)$ or $(n,1)$ you increase by one the amount collected;
 - if you get coupons $(m+1,m+2), \cdots (n-1,n)$ you increase by two the amount collected;
 - in any other case you remain with the collected amount;

Case 1 corresponds to $2$ extractions, case 2 to $n-m-1$ extractions and case 3 gives the remaining $m-1$ extractions 
of the total $n$.
When $m=0$ we have $0,n,0$, while if it were $m=1$ (but it cannot occur) we would have $2, n-2,0$, then when
$m=n-1$ we have $[2,0,n-2]$ and for $n=m$ it is $[0,0,n]$.

Because of symmetry, it is easy to deduce that the above counting holds whichever type are the $m$ coupon collected.

Therefore the transition matrix for the number of coupons collected, indexed $[0,n] \times [0,n]$,  is
$$
\eqalign{
  & T_{\,m,\,q} \quad \left| {\;0 \le m,q \le n} \right.\quad  =   \cr 
  &  = \left[ {0 = n} \right] + {{\left[ {1 \le n} \right]} \over n}\left( {\left( {m - \left[ {m < n} \right]} \right)\left[ {1 \le m} \right]\left[ {q = m} \right]
 + 2\left[ {1 \le m} \right]\left[ {q = m + 1} \right] + \left( {n - m - \left[ {1 \le m} \right]} \right)\left[ {q = m + 2} \right]} \right) \cr} 
$$

where $[P]$ denotes the [*Iverson bracket*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)
$$
\left[ P \right] = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   1 & {P = TRUE}  \\
   0 & {P = FALSE}  \\
 \end{array} } \right.
$$

For example, for $n=4,5$ the matrices are
$$
\eqalign{
  & {\bf T}_{\,4}  = \left( {\matrix{
   0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \cr 
   0 & 0 & {1/2} & {1/2} & 0  \cr 
   0 & 0 & {1/4} & {1/2} & {1/4}  \cr 
   0 & 0 & 0 & {1/2} & {1/2}  \cr 
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \cr 
 } } \right)  \cr 
  & {\bf T}_{\,5}  = \left( {\matrix{
   0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \cr 
   0 & 0 & {2/5} & {3/5} & 0 & 0  \cr 
   0 & 0 & {1/5} & {2/5} & {2/5} & 0  \cr 
   0 & 0 & 0 & {2/5} & {2/5} & {1/5}  \cr 
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & {3/5} & {2/5}  \cr 
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \cr 
 } } \right) \cr} 
$$

The matrix exhibits an interesting symmetry.
Its eigenvalues follows a regular path $\left\{ {{k \over h}\quad \left| {\;0 \le k \ne h - 1 \le h} \right.} \right\}$ (for $2 \le h$), with the null value being double.
The matrix is diagonalizable, and we can apply the Markov theory to get various interesting parameters.